# How to check if HTML element is/is not hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my two elements(setProject and setHdc). When clicked, they show other table elements. But I want to make only one group of table elements appear at the same time. for example when the user clicked on "setProject", the "setHdc" element must be hidden. and the same otherwise. Is there any way i can do it as If statment? Or is there a simpler way to do it?

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#setProject ").click(function(){
    $("#test1").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#projectTable1").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#projectTable2").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#projectTable3").fadeToggle("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#setHdc").click(function(){
    $("#hdcTable1").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#hdcTable2").fadeToggle("fast");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: is my question clear?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy - I already have the answer, but thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use

```
 if($(this).is(':visible')){
     doSomething();
 }else{
     doSomethingElse();
 }
```

the `else` part will only work for elements with `display:none`. elements that have `visibility:hidden/opacity:0` will be considered visible

Answer (score 4):

Use the [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
if($('#element').is(':visible'))
{
    //write the code for visible
}
else
{
    // write the invisible code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#setProject ").click(function(){
        $("#setHdc").hide();
        $("#test1").fadeToggle("fast");
        $("#projectTable1").fadeToggle("fast");
        $("#projectTable2").fadeToggle("fast");
        $("#projectTable3").fadeToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#setHdc").click(function(){
        $("#setProject").hide();
        $("#hdcTable1").fadeToggle("fast");
        $("#hdcTable2").fadeToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Just hide the opposing element on the .click event of each element.

Comment: It's not a solution, because it hides my whole element, and user can't choose it anymoore.